# Assigning weights to variables to calculate rank/score of an Agent

Tags: pca, ranking, unsupervised-learning

I have data on Agents behavior history. I want to score each of these Agents based on the attributes. Attributes are both Categorical and Continuous.For this, I want to calculate the score by assigning weights to variables, (ex: 10% to v1, 20% to v2, 50% to v3 etc.,) and then sum up these weights. The resultant score should tell me how good a Agent is. For instance, a score above 500 means they are good Agent . While the threshold can be decided once we get a score, I want to know how I can approach this problem?

I decided to run PCA, from which I can get the PCA scores and hence use coefficients as weights.

For example, if I select the first principal component and take the coefficients,

y1=0.5v1+0.8v2-0.2v3 ,

replacing v1, v2 , v3 with the values of the attributes, I can get a score of each observation.

I am not sure if this is a clever approach. Is there a better way to optimize the weights and calculate the score of each customer? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of these scores? How would any unsupervised method find out how the attributes relate to the agent being 'good'?

Comment: @Juho Kokkala , I want to find a way to find single score from the attributes which I have. I will then use these score to rank order my observations

Comment: @saurabhkumar I am working on a similar problem.Can you tell me what method did you end up using? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few cautions:

First, PCA on a combination of continuous and categorical variables is a little tricky. It's been discussed here many times.

Second, be careful about the direction of the PCs.  It's possible for a PC to be the opposite direction of other PCs.

Third, you are assuming that all the PCs will be about "how good an agent is". Since PCA is designed to get at separate qualities (and, if you choose an orthogonal rotation, qualities that are uncorrelated) this may not be a good assumption.

Fourth, if you add up the PCs then you are weighting each of them equally. It might be better to force an analysis with a single component.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your comments, any suggestions on which method should I use instead? To get individual score of my agents?